# Is there a way to access an iframe's window object from the canvas in FBJS? (facebook)

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

From the facebook canvas, I need to be able to access an iframe window.  Normally you could do this with window.frames, but FJBS doesn't seem to allow access to the window object.

Has anyone figured out how to access window objects?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible now.  I think they have changed the window prototype.

Answer (score 10):

you could try this. Let me know how it works.

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframeId');

// could retrieve window or document depending on the browser
// (if FBJS allows it!?)
var myIframeWin = myIframe.contentWindow || myIframe.contentDocument;

if( !myIframeWin.document ) { //we've found the document
    myIframeWin = myIframeWin.getParentNode(); //FBJS version of parentNode
}
```

Comment: Please edit this answer because this is outdated and can mislead other people looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers handle domain security on the principle of **[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**

And the **[laws of cross domain communication](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)**

Also you will find an interesting read on the creationg of read-write JS APIs on this blog post http://piecesofrakesh.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-build-readwrite-javascript-api.html

Comment: The question does not involve cross-domain scripting. The scripts are injected into Facebook's domain, the same domain where the iframe element lives.

Facebook has changed the underlying prototypes to prevent access.

Comment: are you creating the application in FBML? or iframe mode?
From your comment I gather FBML